# How to preference library in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have imported two library in my project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

now I want to use class HttpServletRequest from package javaee-web-api. Problem is that javax servlet contains this class too and application is using this instead of library what I want to. How I can change it ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the jee api and remove the servlet api? I think jee already contains the full servlet api.

Comment: Care to explain why you *can not do this*?

Comment: because dependency javax.servlet        
 I have in parent project which I cant edit and now I am creating new where I need to use javaee-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it. I can exclude this library:

```
<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

and then it works

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Remove either one. Both classes are in the same namespace/package. `HttpServletRequest` is defined by a standard it should behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a comment now that explains that the `javax.servlet` is coming from the parent pom then I don't think it is possible. It has been discussed before: [Is there anyway to exclude artifacts inherited from a parent POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681759/is-there-anyway-to-exclude-artifacts-inherited-from-a-parent-pom)

If you have any kind of control on the parent pom then you should try to change it to have an optional tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Then it won't be included as a transitive dependency for your child project.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html