# Maven not resolving given nested dependency version

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have given following module in module A:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependecies>
```

And included module A in module B like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.01</version>
    </dependency>
</dependecies>
```

But still `mvn dependency:tree` is showing 3.14.9 version in module B, please help.

```
[INFO] com.example.test:B:jar:1.01
[INFO] +- com.example.test:A:jar:1.01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.9:compile
```

I have also excluded it from all other modules that have 3.14.9 conflicts.
I know I can add okhttp 4.9.2 explicitly in module B but there are many such modules, I don't want to add explicitly 4.9.2 version each time.
For some reason, this is the case only for okhttp, rest other dependencies resolving given version

Comment: Have you rebuild module A? Do you use the newly builded version of A in B?

Comment: @Jens yes, many times. Even cleared cache and restart intellij

Comment: You are using version 1.01 is this correct? Is it deployed in to a Maven repo?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I don't understand, why it should be deployed to maven repo

Comment: I just thought because you are using release versions and not snapshot versions. Usually release versions are in a maven repo

Comment: Actually its in my organisation internal repos, not public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the dependency resolution by enforcing dependency version in dependencyManagement in parent pom as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684291/5859017 in 2nd point. Maybe some dependency in parent pom was causing problem that has okhttp as transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the version of artefact A you are trying to use in module B, can you check if it's the same version you are trying to build using okhttp 4.9.2

Comment: yes its same, I have edited in question.